# Mutated vowels (in german: “Umlaute”) in applescript

Tags: location, applescript

i get the location based on my IP-Adress 
my problem now is that i live in "Würzburg" (Germany) but my script says "W¸rzburg".
How can i get the "¸" to "ü"?

```
--Get the IP
set webadress to do shell script "curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/"
set tURL to "http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/" & webadress

--Get the location
set TID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set webadress to do shell script "curl " & tURL
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ¬
    "<tr><th>City:</th><td>"
set text1 to text item 2 of webadress
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "</td></tr>"
set location to text item 1 of text1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website uses ISO-8859-1, but you can change the encoding with `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8`.

`do shell script "curl http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$(curl http://bot.whatismyipaddress.com/) | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 | sed -En 's|<tr><th>City:</th><td>(.*)</td></tr>|\\1|p'"`